# How to get Text Input In Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm new to Adobe AIR and here is what i'm doing, (please note that i'm doing this by AS3 code:

1. Adding a VGroup to the Canvas control.

   ```
           var vIncomeHeader:VGroup = new VGroup();
           vIncomeHeader.width = 1326;
           vIncomeHeader.height = 29;
           vIncomeHeader.id = "vIncomeHeader";

           canvasIncome.addChild(vIncomeHeader);
   ```
2. Creating and adding a HGroup to the VGroup created in step one.
3. Creating 5 TextInput and adding it to HGroup. First textbox is editable and rest are not editable.

   ```
           var hfIncomeHeader:HGroup = new HGroup();
           var txt:TextInput = new TextInput();

           vIncomeHeader.addElement(hfIncomeHeader);

           var lp:int =0;
           var lp-inner:int =0;

           for (lp=0; lp<10; lp++)
           {

           hfIncomeHeader = new HGroup();                          
           hfIncomeHeader.width = 1326;
           hfIncomeHeader.height = 29;


           //Amount

           txt = new TextInput();                          
           txt.id = "txtAmount_" + lp;                         
           txt.width = 120;                            
           txt.height = 22;                            
           txt.restrict = "0-9.\\";                            
           txt.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, txtChangeIncomeAmount);
           hfIncomeHeader.addElement(txt);



           for (lp-inner=0; lp-inner<4; lp-inner++)
           {    

           //Income Type
           txt = new TextInput();
           txt.id = "txt_" + lp + "_" + lp-inner;
           txt.width = 120;
           txt.height = 22;                            
           hfIncomeHeader.addElement(txt);
           }                           

           }


           //txtChangeIncomeAmount
           protected function txtChangeIncomeAmount(event:Object):void
           {

                   // HOW TO Do IT

           }
   ```

[Second and third steps are part of a for loop from 0 to 10]

Now, what I want to do is to write the number in first textbox and automatically fill the same number to other 4 textboxes of that HGroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set names to your TextInput and then get them by names. Something like that:

```
...
txt.name = "txt_" + lp-inner;
...
protected function txtChangeIncomeAmount(event:Event):void
{
    var txt:TextInput;

    for (var i:uint = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        txt = hfIncomeHeader.getChildByName("txt_" + i) as TextInput;
        txt.text = (event.currentTarget as TextInput).text;
    }
}
```